# how to manage cocoapods autolinking in different targets

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, apple-appclips

I am developing an AppClip for my main project in react-native but I am using a lot of cocoapods in the main project that are not necessary for the clip and in fact push the size of my app clip above the 10mb limit, If I manually remove these from the project the AppClip does build below the size limit but it breaks functionality in the main app.

So my question is, is there any way to remove a pod that is autolinked between different targets in a podfile?

Podfile for reference:

```html
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '12.1'

  target 'mainProject' do
    config = use_native_modules!
    use_react_native!(
      :path => config[:reactNativePath],
      # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
      :hermes_enabled => false
    )
    
    # pod 'cli-platform-ios', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

    pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

    pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

    pod 'RNInAppBrowser', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'


    # pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'


    target 'mainProjectTests' do
      inherit! :complete
      # Pods for testing
    end
    target 'mainProjectAppClick' do
      inherit! :complete
      # Pods for testing
    end
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    use_flipper!()

    post_install do |installer|
      react_native_post_install(installer)
    end
  end
```